# python import a local package

Tags: python, import, package, local

I have trouble to import a local package. The code from github has below structure.

```
/ProjectA
/ProjectA/algorithms/...
/ProjectA/local_packages/internal-python3.zip
/ProjectA/example.py
```

The zip file contains internal.py, setup.py, etc....

When I run the example.py, it gives an ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'interval' at below line of script

```
from interval import Interval
```

Any idea to solve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You've unzipped the zip?

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you have unzipped the file. After that if you want to make a specific folder into a local package, inside the desired folder you need to create a file named **init**.py It can me a blank file

So in the case of interval folder, you need to have
/interval/**init**.py